# OpenVPN connection stops working every 5 days

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, kvm-virtualization, connection, qemu

I've been pulling my hair out over this issue for awhile. For 2 year, i've been running OpenVPN on Ubuntu 18.04 without many issues. As a virtual server on Virtualbox on a Windows host.
Now i've changed the host to Ubuntu 19.10 for awhile, and using KVM/QEMU as a virtualization solution. Still using the virtual server with Ubuntu 18.04 and OpenVPN. 
It has worked well but since some time now, every 5 days after booting the server, all clients are unable to connect anymore. The temporary solution was to just reboot the server but I found out there was an even quicker way. Disconnecting and reconnecting the (virtual) network card of the server also helps. A ritual which I have to keep repeating 5 days later.

Thinking it was a host problem, I built a newly installed Ubuntu 20.04 server and moved the virtual server there. But unfortunately, the problem stays.
Below is a snippet of the Openvpn.log. (I changed the external client IP address to 1.2.3.4 for privacy reasons)

```
May  1 14:33:33 UBSRV ovpn-server[2295]: 1.2.3.4:53856 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]1.2.3.4:53856, sid=c9c686be 9cf0f8ce
May  1 14:34:22 UBSRV ovpn-server[2295]: 1.2.3.4:53851 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
May  1 14:34:22 UBSRV ovpn-server[2295]: 1.2.3.4:53851 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
May  1 14:34:22 UBSRV ovpn-server[2295]: 1.2.3.4:53851 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
May  1 14:34:33 UBSRV ovpn-server[2295]: 1.2.3.4:53856 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
May  1 14:34:33 UBSRV ovpn-server[2295]: 1.2.3.4:53856 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
May  1 14:34:33 UBSRV ovpn-server[2295]: 1.2.3.4:53856 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
May  1 14:43:30 UBSRV ovpn-server[2295]: 1.2.3.4:53956 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]1.2.3.4:53956, sid=282f086d cc3e3b5b
May  1 14:43:31 UBSRV ovpn-server[2295]: 1.2.3.4:53956 tls-crypt unwrap error: bad packet ID (may be a replay): [ #1 / time = (1588337010) Fri May  1 14:43:30 2020 ] -- see the man page entry for --no-replay and --replay-window for more info or silence this warning with --mute-replay-warnings
May  1 14:43:31 UBSRV ovpn-server[2295]: 1.2.3.4:53956 tls-crypt unwrap error: packet replay
```

The server config is as follows:

```
dev tun
proto udp
port 1194
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued/UBSRV_e307a924-b5ae-413a-94af-89a150a03de8.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/UBSRV_e307a924-b5ae-413a-94af-89a150a03de8.key
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
push "block-outside-dns"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
client-to-client
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
keepalive 15 120
remote-cert-tls client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-crypt /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ta.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
user openvpn
group openvpn
persist-key
persist-tun
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
status-version 3
syslog
verb 3
```

I hope anyone has an idea or a hint what to look for. Maybe I will convert the machine back to VirtualBox and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I doubt it's an OpenVPN or your guest OS problem. Because reconnecting virtual NIC from host fixes the issue it's most likely an issue with host and/or hypervisor settings. Even if you reinstalled doesn't means that wrong settings are gone. Which type of virtual NIC are you using? Are you running any sort of firewall manager on you host?

Comment: @NStorm2 I was thinking along the same lines - and was possibly going to suggest changing the NIC specified for the VM in KVM.  I was also thinking about mentioning to check clock drift (but don't think its that). I paused though because I recently (on different OS had a reliable OpenVPN setup die on me until I restarted the OpenVPN server - and I suspect it could be a client/server/connection tracking issue.

Comment: Thanks NStorm and davidgo. It's not a time drift issue, I had that once before and managed to fix it.
The NIC type is 'virtio'. I can change it to either 'e1000e' or 'Hypervisor default. Not much choice there.
I shut down the server, changed it to 'e1000e' and booted it back up. Guess I will have to wait 5 days to see if this did the trick ;-)
I don't have the firewall enabled on the host. Also not on the old one.

Comment: Unfortunately my VPN server stopped working again. Still don't understand anything of it.
The logs reads this again:

May  7 14:48:07 UBSRV ovpn-server[579]: REDACTED:35429 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
May  7 14:48:07 UBSRV ovpn-server[579]: REDACTED:35429 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
May  7 14:48:07 UBSRV ovpn-server[579]: REDACTED:35429 SIGUSR1[soft,tls->error] received, client-instance restarting
=============================================





I have a strong feeling there's a bug in KVM/QEMU networking.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I changed my Ubuntu server with KVM/QEMU to Proxmox 6.2 (based on QEMU version 5).
Uptime is now more than 5 days and VPN still working! Definetely there's some kind of networking bug in version 4.2.0.